# Error building openssl library in windows system with NDK21 for android environment

Tags: android, windows, openssl, android-ndk

I am building openssl on windows 10 with NDK 21 for android studio 3.6. I am following https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems Autoconf method and stuck in this. Is there anyone who has idea about what should be the issue.

Getting this error while following:

apps/bf_prefix.o apps/opt.o apps/s_cb.o apps/s_socket.o
make[1]:/mnt/c/Users/jyotsna/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows- 
          x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android-ar: Command not found
         Makefile:697: recipe for target 'apps/libapps.a' failed
          make[1]: *** [apps/libapps.a] Error 127
          make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/jyot/Downloads/openssl-1.1.1g'
          Makefile:172: recipe for target 'all' failed
          make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: So which files _do_ you have under `/mnt/c/Users/jyotsna/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google announced [NDKPorts](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/02/native-dependencies-in-android-studio-40.html) which ships a precompiled OpenSSL. Just use that.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But I wanted to use GSL also in the android application. I had tried to include using add_subdirectory, but it is not including the library in includes directory.

Comment: I included using add_subdirectory(gsl) in cpp folder but it's not working this way.